# Not able to center rectangle on Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, syntax, kivy

I am totally new to Kivy and trying to make this app screen which is basically supposed to be a blue screen with a white rectangle in its center and some text and a button in that rectangle.

I got some codes from online and tried to create this and am able to make my background blue and have a white rectangle, but I am not able to center it.
Not just that but when I was running the code it gave me a blue background on only quarter of the window and a white SQUARE on the top right -rest of the screen was BLACK! When I increased the size, the black screen disappeared and the blue bg screen was there however with the white rectangle now at the bottom left.

My code is as it is below. Please could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong and also how to center the white rectangle on the blue without any black screens. Thank you!!

```
# import kivy module
import kivy

# this restrict the kivy version i.e
# below this kivy version you cannot
# use the app or software
kivy.require("1.9.1")

# base Class of your App inherits from the App class.
# app:always refers to the instance of your application
from kivy.app import App

# A Widget is the base building block
# of GUI interfaces in Kivy.
# It provides a Canvas that
# can be used to draw on screen.
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

# From graphics module we are importing
# Rectangle and Color as they are
# basic building of canvas.
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window

self.size = Window.size

# class in which we are creating the canvas
class DeliverTodayWidget(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DeliverTodayWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = Window.size

        # Arranging Canvas
        with self.canvas:
            Color(.234, .456, .678, .8)  # set the colour

            # Seting the size and position of canvas
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=(self.center_x, self.center_y),  size =(self.width,
                                        self.height))
                                       # Update the canvas as the screen size change
            self.bind(pos=self.update_rect,size=self.update_rect)

            Color(1, 0, 0, 0, 0.5)  # set the colour
            self.rect2 = Rectangle(pos=(self.center), size=(500,500)
            self.bind(pos=self.update_rect2, size=self.update_rect2)
                # update function which makes the canvas adjustable.

    def update_rect(self, *args):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
        self.rect.size = self.size

    def update_rect2(self, *args):
        self.rect2.pos = self.center


class DeliverTodayApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return DeliverTodayWidget()
DeliverTodayApp().run()
```

I have gone through many websites to search about centering the rectangle including some other pages on stack overflow but none help. Any help would be appreciated.

(P.S. I am using a macOS and pycharm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to set the `self.rect` pos to `self.pos`, not `(self.center_x, self.center_y)`. For `self.rect2` you probably want to set its pos to `self.center_x - 250` and similarly for y. Both of these are because the Rectangle pos describes its bottom left corner.

> Please could someone explain to me what is the syntax error in this line

That line doesn't look to have a syntax error in itself, you probably made a mistake somewhere else in your code.

Comment: that really worked, thank you so much! Just wanna know why is it -250 and how would the measurements change if the square was to be bigger..

Comment: Try putting in some numbers and see how it behaves.